# Band value selection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, band, sentinel-5p

I am working on Sentinel-5p NO2 data in Google Earth Engine. The band value of 'NO2_column_number_density' starts from negative numbers i.e.**(Low : -1.34484e-05**) but I need low value to be start from 0. Is there any filter in Google Earth Engine to start band values from 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can mask the negative pixels so that image band starts from zero. Like this:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-06-06');

var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.0002,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

var image = collection.mean()
var image = image.updateMask(image.gte(0)) //mask pixels less than zero.
Map.addLayer(image, band_viz, 'S5P N02');
Map.setCenter(65.27, 24.11, 4);
```

Comment: Tried this but no luck. Exported masked image as GEOtiff file and opened it in ArcMap still the values starts from Low:2.10116e-07. This low should be zero.